# Delegate pattern in a singleton does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, singleton

**20140115 updated: with working code**

I have a Singleton where I want to use the delegate pattern. When I call the methode with the delegate I get not notified.

**Where is my error? How can I get the delegate pattern to work with `didComposition`?**

Below my debugger and code, the important parts:

#### Debugger

```
2014-01-15 14:31:09.703 Foobar[5854:70b] -[WebApi sandbox] [Line 42] Sandbox call
2014-01-15 14:31:09.707 Foobar[5854:70b] -[WebApi getSurroundStream] [Line 67] Surround Stream call
```

#### WebApi.h - Singleton with the delegate pattern

```c
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"

@class WebApi;
@protocol WebApiDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)didComposition;

@end

@interface WebApi : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager <SingletonDelegate>

@property (assign, nonatomic)id<WebApiDelegate> delegate;

+(WebApi*)sharedInstance;

-(void)sandbox;
-(void)doSurroundComposition;

@end
```

#### WebApi.m

```c
#import "WebApi.h"
#define kApiHost @"http://192.168.0.1"  

@implementation WebApi

-(WebApi*)initWithBaseURL:url {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) { }
    return  self;
}

#pragma mark - Singleton methods
+(WebApi*)sharedInstance
{
    static WebApi *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kApiHost]];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

-(void)sandbox {

    DLog(@"Sandbox called"); 
    // Do AFNetworking Stuff
}

-(void)doSurroundComposition {
    [self sandbox]; 
    DLog(@"do surround composition");
    [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(didComposition)];
}

@end
```

#### SurroundViewController.h

```c
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "Lokation.h"
    #import "WebApi.h"

    @interface SurroundViewController : UICollectionViewController <LokationDelegate, WebApiDelegate>

    @property (strong, nonatomic) Lokation *lokation;

    @end
```

#### SurroundViewController.m (updated with working code)

```c
#import "SurroundViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"

@interface SurroundViewController ()

@end

@implementation SurroundViewController

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.lokation = [[Lokation alloc] init];
        self.lokation.delegate = self;
        [self.lokation getLocation];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [WebApi sharedInstance].delegate = self;
    [[WebApi sharedInstance] doSurroundComposition];

}

-(void)didComposition {
    DLog(@"did load composition");  // will not be called!
}

@end
```

Comment: If you don't set the object to be the delegate, how do you expect it to be called. Also, as your protocol method isn't marked as required, you really should check that the delegate implements the protocol method before you call it - otherwise it's possible that you'll have a crash.

Comment: @Abizern Sometimes you do not see the wood for the trees. So it's helpful to ask, to get in line again and clear the fog that's around the brain. Nobody is perfect all the time.

Comment: TBH it's not a "wood for the trees problem". A delegate method is not being called. The first thing that comes to mind is "Have I set a valid delegate?" The second thing that comes to mind is "Am I actually sending the message to my delegate?" Third thing "Let me put some breakpoints in my code and follow the execution to see if what I am expecting to happen is actually happening". It's not about being perfect, it's about following __basic__ steps to fix your own problems.

Comment: And I can bet you that the very first thing @Wain did was to look through your code looking for the line where you are setting your delegate object.

Comment: @Abizern that's fine. I have a slightly other point of view. But this is not relevant here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `[WebApi sharedInstance]` for the first time, you then need to set the delegate to something. Currently (in the code you show) you aren't setting any delegate. So when the shared instance tries to call the delegate it is simply a no-op.

Comment: Thanks. `[WebApi sharedInstance].delegate = self;` did solve my problem.